# Start Application only once (Mono)

Tags: c#, process, mono, mutex

I'm currently developing an mono application in c#, which I would like to start only once. I know, this can be achieved with mutex. But how can I bring the application to front using mono?
I tried getting the Process via

```
Process.GetProcessByName("AudioCuesheetEditor")
```

but couldn't access the MainWindowHandle.

How can I bring the running application to front?

Thanks for you answers.

EDIT:

Now I have been able to get the MainWindowHandle, but it's a IntPtr. How do I bring this handle to front? I tried

```
Window wRunning = new Window(handle);
wRunning.Present();
```

but that gave me an exception :(.

Comment: You should change the question title.

Comment: It's a winform application?

Comment: Yes, a winform application based on gtk sharp.

Comment: I could really need some help :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to fix it with a file system watcher:

```
        FileSystemWatcher fswRunning = new FileSystemWatcher(Path.GetTempPath() + "AudioCuesheetEditor");
        fswRunning.Filter = "*.txt";
        fswRunning.Changed += delegate(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
            log.debug("FileSystemWatcher called Changed");
            if (pAudioCuesheetEditor != null)
            {
                log.debug("pAudioCuesheetEditor != null");
                pAudioCuesheetEditor.getObjMainWindow().Present();
            }
        };
        fswRunning.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        Boolean bAlreadyRunning = false;
        Process[] arrPRunning = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process pRunning in arrPRunning)
        {
            Boolean bCheckProcessMatch = false;
            if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Unix)
            {
                if (pRunning.HasExited == false)
                {
                    log.debug("pRunning.ProcessName = " + pRunning.ProcessName + " pRunning.MainWindowTitle = " + pRunning.MainWindowTitle);
                    if (pRunning.ProcessName.ToLower().Contains("mono"))
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < pRunning.Modules.Count;i++)
                        {
                            if (pRunning.Modules[i].ModuleName.Contains("AudioCuesheetEditor"))
                            {
                                bCheckProcessMatch = true;
                                i = pRunning.Modules.Count;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
            else
            {
                log.debug("pRunning.ProcessName = " + pRunning.ProcessName);
                if (pRunning.ProcessName == Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName)
                {
                    bCheckProcessMatch = true;
                }
            }
            log.debug("bCheckProcessMatch == " + bCheckProcessMatch);
            if ((pRunning.Id != Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id) && (bCheckProcessMatch == true))
            {
                log.info("Writing to file " + Path.GetTempPath() + "AudioCuesheetEditor" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "message.txt");
                File.WriteAllText(Path.GetTempPath() + "AudioCuesheetEditor" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "message.txt","Present");
                bAlreadyRunning = true;
            }
        }
        log.debug("bAlreadyRunning = " + bAlreadyRunning);
        if (bAlreadyRunning == false)
        {
               //Start Application
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a FSW for this seems like very hacky.

I think the most elegant solution is using IPC.

In particular, I would use DBus. In fact, it's what [Banshee](http://banshee.fm) uses to avoid multiple instances of it being created. So go ahead and check out our source code if you're interested.

Comment: Well is DBus not only for Linux?

Comment: DBus is the general IPC system used in Linux, but that doesn't mean that it doesn't work with Windows or other Unixes, i.e.: AFAIK you can compile DBus libraries with mingw, and furthermore, if you use managed DBUS (dbus-sharp) then you can even compile it with .NET, so it should work

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i tried using NDesk.DBus, but it didn't work with windows. So it seems like DBus is only for linux :(.

Comment: and I don't recommend NDesk.DBus, but dbus-sharp

Comment: Sorry, I only get exceptions when using NDesk.DBus, since it uses a library which seems only available under linux. And I thought NDesk.Dbus is dbus-sharp, I used this (http://www.ndesk.org/DBusSharp)

Comment: I guess you're referring to "Mono.Posix", and I think you can get that library for Windows; other than that, dbus-sharp (the new name for NDeskDbus, as the latter is unmaintained) is managed DBus, so it shouldn't depend on unmanaged dependencies