# DBus-Sharp not working on Windows

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, managed, dbus

Well let me describe what I've done:

- Downloaded https://github.com/mono/dbus-sharp
- Added another project in xamarin studio (monodevelop) and named it "DBus-Sharp"
- Added the reference to my project to "DBus-Sharp" and tried to call

  ```
  Bus bus = Bus.System;
  ```
- got the following exception

  ```
  System.Exception: Unable to open the system message bus. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Die DLL "libsocket": Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x8007007E) kann nicht geladen werden. ---> System.Exception:
  ```

  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

  ```
  at bei DBus.Unix.UnixSocket.socket(Int32 domain, Int32 type, Int32 protocol)
  at bei DBus.Unix.UnixSocket..ctor()
  at bei DBus.Transports.UnixNativeTransport.OpenUnix(String path)
  at bei DBus.Transports.UnixNativeTransport.Open(String path, Boolean abstract)
  at bei DBus.Transports.UnixTransport.Open(AddressEntry entry)
  at bei DBus.Transports.Transport.Create(AddressEntry entry)
  at bei DBus.Connection.OpenPrivate(String address)
  at bei DBus.Connection..ctor(String address)
  at bei DBus.Bus..ctor(String address)
  at bei DBus.Bus.Open(String address)
  at bei DBus.Bus.get_System()
  ```

  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

  ```
  at bei DBus.Bus.get_System()
  at bei AudioCuesheetEditor.MainClass.Main(String[] args) in e:\Projekte\Audio Cuesheet Editor (Windows)\src\AudioCuesheetEditor\MainClass.cs:Zeile 65.
  ```

What I'm doing wrong?!

Comment: As far as I can tell, dbus-sharp doesn't have a windows transport yet.

Comment: I came from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855227/start-application-only-once-mono and there knocte said it would be able with dbus-sharp.